# .Net Project Contains Forms, Classes, Windows Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-services

So I have this project I am working on. In short its a app that integrate data from different systems (Print Management, Telephone Management, Mail Management) to Cost Recovery Systems.

[image]

Its a project that contains:

- Forms for settings and viewing logs.
- Classes that manage integration functions for each PMS, TMS, MMS and CRS.
- Windows Service that triggers integration tasks on set schedules.
- Entity Framework that connects to a data model used for managing
  clients, servers, and logs.

The depencies of objects is shown below:
[image]

My question is can all these components exist in the same project (which is a Windows Forms App).
For if I publish or create an installer for this project, I need to sure that once installed, the Windows Service will be listed under Services.

**UPDATE:**

So based on comments: Would this then be a better approach.
Windows App Project
Windows Service App Project that references the Windows App Project in order to use its module's functions.
Installer that installs both the App and WS.

[image: Should I then]

Comment: No they can't. A Windows Forms app and a Windows service are two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jmc's comment is accurate; you can't put these in one project. You can put a windows service *project* and a windows forms *project* into a single overall *solution* though. How all this is bundled up for deployment/install is a separate question though. You could certainly have an install process that installs a windows service and a windows forms app but the individual projects will have different outputs (e.g. one exe that is a windows service, another that is a forms app, a third project that outputs a DLL that represents a shared data layer used by both EXEs..)

Comment: What does VS 2019 use nowadays to create Installers where you include multiple projects? I know the VS 2017 had an Installer Project, but seems VS 2019 doesnt support that anymore.

Comment: Same as 2017, I thought: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects ?